# Is it written as $x$-axis, $x$- axis or $x$ -axis?

Tags: soft-question, notation

This question is more about typesetting. I have seen the axes been referred to as:
$x$-axis, $x$ -axis, and $x$- axis. When referring to multiple axes I have seen: $x$- and $y$- axes, $x$- and $y$-axis, $x$ and $y$-axis,  $x$ and $y$-axes, and multiple variations thereof.

Is there a preferred or proper way of typing this or is it more about personal taste? Personally I think $x$-axis and $x$ and $y$-axes looks the best. I don't feel this belongs in a meta nor do I believe it fits into an English stackexchange.

Comment: Without question $x$-axis for a single one. I have far less of an opinion about $x$[-] and $y$-axis[axes]

Comment: Personally, I prefer to write "$x$- and $y$-axes" without spaces, rather than leaving a space in between.  Also, I added the `notation` tag to the question.

Comment: @obscurans This as well as upright/italic d for derivatives/integrals are both missing from a lot of mathematical typesetting books. A lot of people seem to have different opinions on it too. Surely there is a "correct" way?

Comment: I wouldn't say there is a correct way as there are conventional ways, and when there is disagreement, that is reflective of a lack of convention and consensus.  When writing for publication, follow the publication's style guide; when writing in other venues where there is no outside prescription, I'd pick whichever one of the common styles annoys me the least, aesthetically speaking. :-)

Comment: Definitely "$x$-axis" (ie, "$x$-[nospace]axis"). The form "$x$- and $y$-axes" (ie, "$x$-[space]and $y$-[nospace]axes"), and more generally "$x$-, $y$-, and $z$-axes", is consistent with the hyphenation rules of grammar, as in "pre-[space]and post-war Europe" and "fifth-, sixth-, and seventh-century art".

Comment: I most definitely try and write $x\,\mathrm{d}x$(note space) but most people aren't a stickler. I agree conventions wherever you're writing are controlling, but I don't know if there's universal consensus on what they are.

Comment: In any case, when writing for yourself, you can do what you like. If/when you submit your work for publication, journal editors will impose whatever convention they prefer. If you have aspirations of publishing in a particular journal, you should check their website for style guides. In general, it can help to browse books on mathematical/technical writing; Donald Knuth's "Mathematical Writing" is now [freely available (PDF link via mit.edu)](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/reviewing-papers/knuth_mathematical_writing.pdf). (It doesn't seem to cover this particular issue, but it's an excellent read.)

Comment: @Blue Thank you for book by Knuth. It seems much better than a lot of the other work I have come across. I also think that personal style is important. It what makes you stand out.

Comment: @HabdichGefangen I agree that surely there is a correct way. Namely my way. In this case, the correct way is "$x$-axis" and "$x$- and $y$-axes".  (Of course, many people will agree that there is a correct way but will disagree about which way that is.)

Answer (score 0):

To me, x-axis is the proper form, but that's to me.  Lots of people that I know use like that, but I've met some people who use it like x- axis.  I really don't think there is a proper way though cause you could put (x-axis/x- axis/x -axis) even x axis in and it would work on google.  from just looking this question up, articles just use x-axis, but feel free to do whatever form you want!